# match comma separated values in a string with table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As part of a stored procedure I receive a string of names separated by commas. The names can be first name, last name, full name or something in between.

How can I find out if the name exists in my table?

```
DECLARE @NameString
SET @NameString = Max,John World,Miller,Peter F, Will
```

Table:

```
ID  Name
1   10_Max_Power
2   11_Tim_Miller
3   87_John_World
4   12_Peter_Foo
5   3123_Tom_Miller
6   323_Jessica_Bar
```

Desired result:

```
ID  Name
1   10_Max_Power
2   11_Tim_Miller
3   87_John_World
4   12_Peter_Foo
5   3123_Tom_Miller
```

Comment: `Peter Foo` is a desired result when `Peter F` is supplied (as an example)?  So they are CONTAINS matches ignoring whatever those numbers are at the beginning of `Name`?

Comment: Yes, ideally it should match all rows with `Peter F`. E.g. `WHERE Name LIKE '%Peter%F%'`

Comment: So `'Peter F'` matches `'Peter DelFudge'` and `'Stompeterofell Diorgio'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, don't pass a delimited parameter, use a table type parameter. Then you can do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Names table (Name nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO @Names (Name)
VALUES('Max'),
      ('John World'),
      ('Miller'),
      ('Peter F'),
      ('Will');

SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.Name
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @Names N
              --Rather than inline the REPLACE you could add Computed Column
              --to your table type variable/parameter.
              WHERE YT.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(N.Name,' ','[_]'),'%'));
```

If you "must" use a delimited string then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` (I assume you're using a fully supported version of SQL Server as there's nothing to say you aren't):

```sql
DECLARE @NameString nvarchar(4000)
SET @NameString = N'Max,John World,Miller,Peter F, Will';

SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.Name
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT (@NameString,',')
              WHERE YT.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(REPLACE(N.Name,' ','[_]')),'%')); --TRIM because Will has a leading space
```

I do, however, also recommend fixing your design. A "name" with a value of `10_Max_Power` is breaking normalisation rules. Clearly the `10` is something else other than the name. It's also clear you want to find people who's Forename or Surname might be the value. Really, therefore, your `Name` column should be *at least* 3 column; `Prefix` (or whatever the number represents), `Forename` and `Surname` (and optionally a column to Middle Name(s)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I use SQL Server 2016, so I have to work with `LTRIM(RTRIM(Name)`. I indeed must a use a delimited string. Your solution unfortunately doesn't bring the desired result for full names.

Comment: Fixed, @jonas .

Comment: @jonas Why *must* you use a delimited string? Which app do you have that forces you to do this? Also, you could just split the string and insert into a table variable first